# How to embed Plotly graphs into html with live data?

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

How to embed Plotly graphs in html or websites with live data? My team is given a task to show data visualization in a website with live data. I searched online and found this- https://plot.ly/python/embedding-plotly-graphs-in-HTML/